# cannot call javascript method from within tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am trying to make a javascript method call from within the tinymce editor on click event on a piece of text written inside the editor, but it is not working. Tinymce version 4 is being used by me.

Below mentioned is the code snippet. Though i can successfully call the inline alert method as in second div, i am unable to call my custom javascript method as in first div.
Suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function customMethod(){
  alert('custom method not being called !!');
}
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  valid_elements: "*[*]"
});
</script>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%">

        <div onclick="customMethod();">Call custom method.</div>
        <div onclick="alert('alert called');">Call Alert.</div>
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: First you add onclick as valid attribute to your divs (see tinymce configuration paramter valid_elements). Here is an example configuration

```
valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover|onclick]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
    "#div,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
    "-span[data-mce-type],hr",
```

Second option is to add this setup parameter you your tinymce config catching each onclick event in the editor

```
setup : function(ed) {
    // Display an alert onclick
    ed.on('click', function(evt) {
        console.log('User clicked the editor. Element:', evt.target);
        if (evt.target.className == 'do_1') alert('do_1');
        if (evt.target.className == 'do_2') alert('do_2');
    });
},
```

You may want to have a look at this tinymce fiddle to see it in action: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/QXdaab